# How to restrict what tags are fetched in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags

I have this PHP script to fetch tags (as we use WordPress as a CMS, the tags are "categories" for our partners).... However, I'm trying to free up "tags" to be used on blog posts - but currently the code below fetches ALL tags - how can I restrict this to only tags I specify (happy to enter each Tag ID)

Here is the code:

```
<?php
        $tags = get_tags('order=ASC&orderby=name);
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
            <?php $tag_name = $tag->slug;

            echo '<div class="col-md-12 padbot50" id="tabs-' . $tag->slug . '">';

            echo '<div class="green_txt font20">' .$tag->name. '</div>';
            //echo $tag_name;

           $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=> 11, 'tag' => $tag_name, 'orderby' => 'slug', 'order' => 'ASC' );
            query_posts( $args );
            // The Loop
            ?>
                    <div class="row">
                      <?php
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'medium', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
                    $post_id = get_the_ID(); 
                    ?>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-7 pad10 center"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="partners_container">
                            <div class="row" style="height:125px;">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="left"> <img src="<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>" height="100%"  alt="Volo Commerce Partners - Multichannel Automated Back Office Software. eBay, Amazon, Rakuten" title="Volo Commerce Partners - Multichannel eCommerce Software. Stock & Inventory Management"/><div class="partner-more-icon"></div></div></div>

                            </div>
                          <div class="padtop10" style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;color:#f08f00!important;"> <?php echo '<div>' . the_title() . '</div>';?> </div>
                          <div class="padtop10 left"> <?php echo '<div>' . the_field('partner_page_description', $post_id ) . '</div>';?>  </div>
                        </div>
                      </a> </div>
                      <?php
                    endwhile; 
                        ?>
                  </div>
      </div>
      <?php
        wp_reset_postdata(); }?>
```

If anyone could be so kind to tell me how I fetch ONLY certain tag ID's - that would be absolutely perfect!

Thanks muchly!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at using `WP_Query` instead of `query_posts()`. You can then specify exactly which tags you'd like to include/exclude. Check out the codex for specific example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: @trysmudford - I'm not overly familiar with WP_Query and how to use it, I will have a look over the link you provided and see if it's easy to change over, or if there is a method from query_posts. Thanks for taking the time to reply, I appreciate it as I'm stuck atm.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of `WP_Query` which should get you started:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'field' => 11
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tag',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'field' => array( /* Your Tag IDs */ ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$post_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) :
        $post_query->the_post();

        // Inner loop stuff code

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for including a VERY helpful answer - I found out that get_tags supports "include" and "exclude" - as per Wordpress Codex

Comment: Glad to hear it! Definitely read up on `WP_Query` at some point, it's a tonne better than `query_posts`!

Comment: I think that is the issue, I'm not massively familiar with it, so I tend to tread around it - I DEFINITELY will take your advice and read up on WP_Query, but a personal thanks for taking the time to give me an example and some tips :)

Answer (score 0):

`get_tags` function accepts `include` argument. You could pass by it ids of tags you want to get.

```
$tags = get_tags('order=ASC&orderby=name');
```

change to

```
$tags = get_tags('order=ASC&orderby=name&include=12,45,67');
```

12, 45 and 67 are ids of tags

[get_tags on codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags)